# Why i am getting this warning while receiving and using the JSON response

Tags: javascript, json

i am receiving and using the json response through java script and i am getting an warning while compiling through Closure compiler

```
 JSC_INEXISTENT_PROPERTY: Property example never defined on json.response.res at line 150 character 12
var company = json.response.res.example.comp[0]["value"];
```

why this happens but i am receiving the output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because that property will only exist on runtime as it's loaded from an external source the closure compiler can't see it and will warn you that you are probably (from the viewpoint of the compiler) accessing an undefined variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable all warnings by using the **@warning_level QUIET** directive

for example:

```
// ==ClosureCompiler==
// @compilation_level ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS
// @output_file_name default.js
// @warning_level QUIET
// ==/ClosureCompiler==
```

But you will still need to export the functions that are called from your html pages externally.